# Proxy for macOS with support for HTTP(S)

Tags: proxy, http

I want a free proxy with preferably a GUI for macOS which supports
 
1) HTTPS proxying where I can install a certificate and modify the requests in between.
2) HTTP CONNECT method so that I can open a tunnel with the end server
3) HTTPS over HTTPS between all endpoints
4) HTTP over HTTP (CONNECT) between all endpoints
5) SOCKS support
6) Proxy chains

I am also open to suggestions which satisfy at least 3 of the 6 above but point 2 is compulsory. I tried squidman and charlesproxy but they don't satisfy my requirements. mitmproxy does not support HTTP CONNECT tunnels.

Comment: Thanks for migrating it. Didn't know this site existed